# How do I disable the description on text labels (Windows)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, desktop-customization

Every now and then I find a computer which has this setting enabled and all the searches in the world have not helped me find a way to turn it off:

[image: example of annoying text]

I have a feeling it might be related to accessibility settings or with MS Office, but I don't even know what to search for. It is happening on Windows 7, but I've seen it since the XP days, and it might as well happen on Windows 10.

What menu option or registry setting is controlling this feature? I can see that it affects Windows dialogs (Folder Options, Appearance Settings), but I also found out it affects other programs (e.g.: When I installed the Java Development Kit, the installer had extra descriptions for the features that I could select to be installed).

Comment: I believe this is an accessibility option.  Probably something to do with blind settings for screen readers. Have you looked at all the accessibility options in control panel? How about compared settings in the registry here `HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility`?

Comment: @Appleoddity: You nailed it. BlindAccess had On=1 and it was stuck like that no matter what I tried to change in Control Panel (Narrator, High Contrast). Once I set it to 0 and rebooted, everything came back to normal. Thanks!